# Serializing Wagtail pages programmatically

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, wagtail

Suppose I have defined a Wagtail endpoint with all the (`api_fields` set up the way I want them in the model):

```
class EventEndpoint(BaseAPIEndpoint):
    model = Event
```

In this case, `Event` is subclass of the Wagtail `Page` class.

I have another view (an old school Django view function), which sends various information from a few models that might look like this:

```
{
  "motd": "...",
  "opening_times": [ ... ],
  ...
}
```

I would like to nest the result of some queries inside that function, like so:

```
{
  "motd": "...",
  "opening_times": [ ... ],
  ...,
  "events_today": { /* serialized result */ }
}
```

Where `events_today` might contain a the serialized result of Events

How can I programmatically serialize the result of a query (say `Event.objects.filter(...)`) to inject into that view, in the same way that `BaseAPIEndpoint` does it?